# Can I overload/create a postfix unary operator?

Tags: ruby

I'd like to create two unary-postfix operators `!` and `!!` for the class `Numeric` in ruby. I have it defined like this so far

```
class Numeric
  def !
    (1..self).inject(:*)
  end

  def !!
    if self.even?
      (2..self).step(2).inject(:*)
    else
      (1..self).step(2).inject(:*)
    end
  end
end
```

However, this means that I must call `5.!` and `5.!!`. I know that you can define unary prefix operators such as `+@` and `-@`, but I was wondering if I could define a unary postfix operator so I can call `5!` and `5!!` instead of `5.!` and `5.!!`.

Comment: I didn't know `!` would be a valid method name, sweet!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. First, there are no postfix operators in Ruby, so the parser couldn't identify one. Secondly, even if we had postfix operators, a trailing exclamation mark is part of a method name, so if you have in your program a *foo!*, it would be interpreted as method `foo!`, not as `foo` with `!` applied.

Comment: Thank you. I had assumed not, but sometimes I learn new thinks from SO. Nice explanation.